# Counting the max of elements based on stack operations c++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, data-structures, stack

You are given a stack of N integers. In one operation, you can either pop an element from the stack or push any popped element into the stack. You need to maximize the top element of the stack after performing exactly K operations. If the stack becomes empty after performing K operations and there is no other way for the stack to be non-empty, print -1.

I'm dynamically allocating the memory and then releasing the memory. I am unable to understand why I'm facing this issue.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int n, x, max;
cin >> n;
cin >> x;
int* arr = new int[n];
    //Storing the values from the last, since the first element represents 
    //top of the stack, so the first element would be latest element which 
    //will be pushed into the stack
for (int i = n; i > 0; i--)
{
    cin >> arr[i];
}
max = arr[n];
    //Finding the max by iterating from the last position to the no of 
    //stack operations performed.
for (int i = n; i >= x; i--)
{
    if (arr[i] > max)
    {
        max = arr[i];
    }
}
cout << max;
delete arr;
return 0;
}
```

Input :

```
6 4
1 2 4 3 3 5
```

Expected Output :

```
4
```

Error:

```
Error Message : Debug Error ! Program :- Heap Corruption detected : after 
normal block c#2368 at 0x01d21e30. CRT detected that the application wrote 
memory after end of heap buffer.
```

Comment: why do you not use `std::vector` ? or for the sake of the example you could use `std::stack`

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I thought of std::stack but I was not sure on how to iterate through it and compare the values.

Comment: btw both your loops iterate from end till first element (out-of-bounds aside for the moment). You could simply say that `arr` contains the elements in reverse order and turn both loops into forward ones. Wont have any impact on the result, but the code will be a bit simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an array of size *n* the valid index are from 0 up to `n-1`, not from 1 to *n*

Warning when you allocate an array with *new* you have to deallocate it with `delete []`

I also encourage you to check when you read a value that the reading success, else the current container is not set and *all* the next read will do nothing

For instance from your code :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n, x, max;

  if ((! (cin >> n)) || (n < 1))
    cerr << "invalid size" << endl;
  else if ((! (cin >> x)) || (x < 0) || (x >= n))
    cerr << "invalid min index" << endl;
  else {
    int* arr = new int[n];
    //Storing the values from the last, since the first element represents 
    //top of the stack, so the first element would be latest element which 
    //will be pushed into the stack
    for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      if (!(cin >> arr[i])) {
        cerr << "invalid value" << endl;
        return 0;
      }
    }
    max = arr[n-1];
    //Finding the max by iterating from the last position to the no of 
    //stack operations performed.
    for (int i = n-2; i >= x; i--)
    {
      if (arr[i] > max)
        {
          max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    cout << max << endl;
    delete arr; // must be delete [] arr;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Out of the fact I check an integer was enter I also check the size/min index are strictly positive and also check the validity of the min index

It is also useless to loop to find the max comparing the`arr[n-1]` with itself, so the first considered index is `n-2`

It seems strange to fill the array from the last index

You use an array but you can also use a `vector<int>` as well, `std::vector` are very practical

Compilation and executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra v.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
aze
invalid size
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
-1
invalid size
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
3 qsd
invalid min index
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
3 4
invalid min index
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
6 4
1 2 4 3 3 5
2
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Note the result is 2 rather than 4 because of the shift in the index, if you want the index starts by 1 for the user do

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n, x, max;

  if ((! (cin >> n)) || (n < 1))
    cerr << "invalid size" << endl;
  else if ((! (cin >> x)) || (x < 1) || (x > n))
    cerr << "invalid min index" << endl;
  else {
    x -= 1;

    int * arr = new int[n];
    //Storing the values from the last, since the first element represents 
    //top of the stack, so the first element would be latest element which 
    //will be pushed into the stack
    for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      if (!(cin >> arr[i])) {
        cerr << "invalid value" << endl;
        return 0;
      }
    }
    max = arr[n-1];
    //Finding the max by iterating from the last position to the no of 
    //stack operations performed.
    for (int i = n-2; i >= x; i--)
    {
      if (arr[i] > max)
        {
          max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    cout << max << endl;
    delete arr; // must be delete [] arr;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra v.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
6 4
1 2 4 3 3 5
4
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Execution under *valgrind* indicating the wrong `free arr`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==3761== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3761== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3761== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3761== Command: ./a.out
==3761== 
6 4
1 2 4 3 3 5
4
==3761== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==3761==    at 0x48491EC: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:576)
==3761==    by 0x10BE7: main (in /tmp/a.out)
==3761==  Address 0x4bcb388 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 alloc'd
==3761==    at 0x48485F0: operator new[](unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:417)
==3761==    by 0x10A9F: main (in /tmp/a.out)
==3761== 
==3761== 
==3761== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3761==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3761==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 22,296 bytes allocated
==3761== 
==3761== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3761== 
==3761== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3761== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: `delete arr;` should be `delete[] arr;`

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 oh yes I missed that change, thank you, I edited my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! This Valgrind looks awesome, I will give it a try.

Comment: @DebabrataPonda yes _valgrind_ is a fantastic tool, use it even when it seems  your code is correct

Answer (score 2):

There are several bugs in your code: three indexation bugs and one memory deallocation bug. First of all, In C++ array indexation always starts from 0. So first valid index of n-element array is 0 and the last valid index is n-1.

1) Due to these reasons first loop should be like this:

```
for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) { ... }
```

2) Bottom element, which you call 'max', should be initialized like this:

```
max = arr[n-1];
```

3) Same observation about the second loop:

```
for (int i = n-2; i >= x; i--) { ... }
```

4) Deallocation of array should be performed with operator `delete[]` instead of `delete`. Otherwise you will have a memory leak and undefined behavior. [Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) you can find some additional information about these operators:

```
delete[] arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the requirement straight in your head:

> You are given a stack of N integers. In one operation, you can either pop an element from the stack or push any popped element into the stack. You need to maximize the top element of the stack after performing exactly K operations. If the stack becomes empty after performing K operations and there is no other way for the stack to be non-empty, print -1.

- So, if N is 0 you print -1, otherwise...
- If K is 0 you print top(), otherwise...
- If K is 1 you have to pop() because you've got nothing to push, so if N was 1 your stack is empty and you must print -1, otherwise print top(): whatever your 2nd-top element happened to be; otherwise...
- if x <= N, you can pop x - 1 elements then push the largest of those back on the top of the stack

  - if x == N, note that means you still won't have popped the final value from the stack, so if it's the largest element you're out of luck: you'll have to push the 2nd-largest back on the top of the stack
    otherwise...
- if x > N, you can pop all the elements, waste any operations until you've only got 1 operation left (by alternately pushing any one of the not-largest values back then if you have another op to waste popping it off), then using the last op to push the largest value back on the stack; this is *equivalent* to finding the largest value in the stack

So, code that always finds the smallest element in the top "x" stack elements doesn't model the stack operations you're supposed to have available.

Now, just because you understand what value your program should return doesn't mean you shouldn't model the operations accurately.  It sounds to me like you should use a stack, push, pop and top operations, and keep track of the values you've popped so you can push them back if necessary, and you may need to be able to find the largest you've popped to specifically put it back.

To do all that, it's easiest to use the [`std::stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) data structure, and say [`std::multiset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) to store the popped elements in sorted order (so you can find the largest one easily).

Code looks like this.  It can be made more efficient/shorter, but I'll leave that to you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <stack>

#define ASSERT(WHAT, MSG) \
    do { \
        if (!(WHAT)) { \
            std::cerr << "ASSERTION FAILURE AT LINE " \
                << __LINE__ << ": " #WHAT "\n" << MSG << '\n'; \
        } \
    } while (false)

#define DBG(MSG) std::cout << "DBG :" << __LINE__ << " " << MSG << '\n'

// helper functions to be able to stream out containers we're using...
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::multiset<int>& s)
{
    os << "{ ";
    for (const auto& x : s) std::cout << x << ' ';
    return os << '}';
}

// note this makes a deep copy of the stack (because "s" is passed by value
// not by reference), so we can pop all the elements destructively
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::stack<int> s)
{
    os << "{ ";
    while (!s.empty())
    {
        std::cout << s.top() << ' ';
        s.pop();
    }
    return os << '}';
}

int main()
{
    std::stack<int> s;
    std::multiset<int> popped;

    int n, k;

    ASSERT(std::cin >> n >> k, "input must have parseable int values for n and k");

    DBG("n " << n << ", k " << k);
    ASSERT(n >= 0, "n must not be negative");
    ASSERT(k >= 0, "k must not be negative");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        int x;
        ASSERT(std::cin >> x, "input must have parseable int for value #" << i + 1);
        s.push(x);
    }

    DBG("initial stack " << s);

    if (n == 0)
        std::cout << -1 << '\n';
    else if (k == 0)
        std::cout << s.top() << '\n';
    else if (k == 1)
    {
        if (n == 1)
            std::cout << -1 << '\n';
        else
        {
            s.pop(); // have to use up our k1 operation as a pop
            std::cout << s.top() << '\n';
        }
    }
    else if (k <= n) // can't pop all the values
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < k; ++i)
        {
            DBG("popping " << s.top());
            popped.insert(s.top()); // add to popped...
            s.pop(); // ...and remove from stack
        }
        DBG("popped k-1 elements (sorted) " << popped);
        DBG("stack " << s);
        // use the last operation to put the largest popped value back
        // (if the stack's has size 2 or more, could pop another one instead -
        //  no way to know which is better, but if the values are random then
        //  the max of all the popped elements is likely to be more than any
        //  given element)
        s.push(*popped.rbegin());  // largest value seen...
        std::cout << s.top() << '\n';
    }
    else // k > n so can pop all the values...
    {
        DBG("k > n");
        while (!s.empty())
        {
            popped.insert(s.top());
            s.pop();
        }
        // waste however many spare operations we have...
        for (int i = 0; i < k - n - 1; ++i)
            if (i % 2 == 0) // on first, third, fifth iteration...
            {
                DBG("push " << *popped.begin());
                s.push(*popped.begin());  // push lowest value seen back to stack...
                popped.erase(popped.begin());  // ...remove it from popped multiset
            }
            else
            {
                DBG("pop " << s.top());
                popped.insert(s.top());
                s.pop();
            }
        DBG("popped elements (sorted) " << popped);
        DBG("stack " << s);
        s.push(*popped.rbegin());  // push largest value...
        std::cout << s.top() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: You might not be "allowed" (by your teacher/tutor) to use `std::stack` and `std::multiset`, but if you can't get the program right using them first, there's no point trying to get it right while mixing in the hassle of using `new[]` and `delete[]` too.